# Update animate property before animation start

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm doing the following animation on an element using jquery animate. The distance value changes before the animation is started so I want to update the animate property value. How can I do this? I used the `start` callback function as shown but it doesn't update the animation.

```
el.delay(delay).animate({
     top: -distance
},{
     duration:700,
     start:function(e){
         e.props.top = -($(e.elem).offset().top  - $(".navigation").offset().top);
}
})
```

Comment: I guess you are missing the unit `(+px)`

Comment: in the start callback or in the params?

Comment: Wherever you are assigning `css properties`

Comment: I added the `px` but no change in the animation!

Comment: Can you share executable demo or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Thank you for the help but I figured the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer on how to update an animation roperty on the fly. `start` is a callback where it gets fired when the animation start but the modifications done to the `props` object doesn't get reflected in the animation! For this, `step` callback is ideal and it let's us change the fx object on each animation step. Following is the solution I figured out.

```
el.delay(delay).animate({
     top: -distance + 'px'
},{
     duration:700,
     step:function(now,fx){
         if(now == 0){
             fx.end = -($(fx.elem).offset().top  - $(".navigation").offset().top);
         }
  }
})
```

I change the prop value when the first step is fired and after that I ignore the rest of the steps. Thank you every one who helped me! :)